# How to force iCloud profile photo to update

Tags: macos, icloud

So my iCloud profile picture is synced across most of my devices, except one of my computers and strictly in the app store on one of my other computers. My iPhone and iMac are perfectly up to date. Is there a way to force an update? I've cleared the cached files on the computers and no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have done major steps like clearing cache, the following is a tweak which also allows you to sync the photo in all your Apple devices. Keep this a try

- First, open Messages from your iPhone.
- Tap the ellipsis (•••) button at the top, then "Share Name and Photo."

Once you see the Share your Name and Photo with the Friends splash screen, tap the "**Choose Name and Photo**" button to continue. On the next screen, your Display Name will be listed as whatever name is associated with your Apple ID, but you can change it to whatever you want. Only one field needs to be filled out, so you can just choose a first or last name or special moniker or nickname.

As for the photo, if you've set a custom photo for yourself in the Contacts app or have already created a Memoji, you'll see those options in the large circles above your display name. You can swipe through the options and select the one you'd like to use. If you want something different, there should be a "View More" option in one of the circles.

Once you've selected one you like, tap the "**Continue**" button at the bottom, and you'll get a prompt asking to "**Use This Photo Everywhere**?" It states that using the new image will change the photo associated with your Apple ID and in your My Card in the Contacts app. Tap "**Use**" to continue.

[image]

On the last page, you'll be asked to choose who you share your name and photo with. You can choose to share it automatically with "**Contacts Only**" or one a case-by-case basis with "**Always Ask.**"

By default, "**Always Ask**" is recommended to maximize your privacy, which will display a permissions prompt within each conversation's thread, where you can choose "Share" or hit the (x) to keep it hidden.

This tweak might help you to sync the photo.

Comment: That totally seems to have done that trick! Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks I just did this on a newly installed Mac and it worked. It takes some time until the personal Card in Contacts reflects the profile picture.

What it doesn't affect is the profile picture shown for the iCloud account in System Settings and the local User account picture.